# How to use Ionic with Meteor and React

Tags: angularjs, meteor, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building a mobile application using Meteor 1.4 and React with cordova.
I am looking for a Mobile UI Framework and the best one out there seems to be Ionic. But I am just not sure how I can use ionic with React.

I looked at packages like Meteoric and Reactionic. But Meteoric is no longer being maintained it seems and Reactionic is just a clone of Meteoric without dependency on Meteor.

The biggest issue to me seems to be using Angular and React together. I thought I could just download ionic locally to my project from [here](http://code.ionicframework.com/). But I can't find any good documentation or article talking about using js features.

Any help would be appreciated. I am still open to moving to some other Mobile UI Framework if it fits well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going ahead with using onsen.io. Mostly because their docs are amazing and fit the suite. You can check them out [here](https://onsen.io/v2/docs/guide/react/)

Read article about using Onsen with Meteor : [here](https://onsen.io/blog/meteor-mobile-app-onsenui/)

This react guid is really helping me as well. Read about it [here](https://onsen.io/v2/docs/guide/react/)

I have to thank Kaiyes who suggested me about this [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-use-ionic-with-meteor-and-react/28571/2?u=aminhas)